# How to change notification title color without creating custom view

Tags: android, android-notifications

I just wanted to change notification title text color. I know I can use custom remote view but I don't want to create a full layout only to change text color. Anyone can help me getting out this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can reference this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setColor(int))

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```